# Conditional column in SQL Server based in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I'm looking for a solution to have a version column on my table based on another column.

I have a column "document No" in my table. Every time I insert a new row with the same document no, I would like to increase the column version.

I know I can it by the back-end. But, it means I have first to read the table and then insert. My idea is to optimize the performance and leave it with SQL Server.

Is It possible?

```
pk    DocNo  Version
---------------------
1     ABC     0
2     CBD     0
3     ABC     1
4     FGH     0
5     ABC     2
```

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL Query or a Trigger or a Stored Procedure?

Comment: One option is to use `row_number()` to generate the version in your select query. Or write a stored procedure to perform the insert. Or use trigger to update the version

Comment: @Angelo, I'm looking for ideas. I don't want to execute a procedure to insert the data. I think a trigger could be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can parameterize your query (as in a stored procedure), AND your primary key is set to `IDENTITY`, you can use something along the lines of:

```sql
    INSERT INTO TableA (DocNo, Version)
    (SELECT TOP 1 'XYZ',ISNULL(MAX(Version)+1,0) 
      FROM TableA WHERE DocNo = 'XYZ')
```

I used `'XYZ'` where you would place your parameter like:

```sql
    INSERT INTO TableA (DocNo, Version)
    (SELECT TOP 1 @DocNo,ISNULL(MAX(Version)+1,0) 
      FROM TableA WHERE DocNo = @DocNo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Stored Procedure Solution

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tableUpsert(@DocNo varchar(100))
AS
  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
  BEGIN TRAN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE DocNo = @DocNo)
      UPDATE dbo.YourTable
      SET Version = Version + 1
      WHERE DocNo = @DocNo;
    ELSE
      INSERT dbo.YourTable(DocNo, Version)
      VALUES(@DocNo, 1);
  COMMIT
```

Code is pretty self-explanatory. If the record exists, you update by incrementing your VersionNumber column and if it doesn't, then insert a new record with default VersionNumber of 1. Note the use of UPDLOCK to ensure that only your specific process is currently updating the record.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insert trigger`. In the trigger, update the `Version` by getting last `version` of same `DocNo` and increment by 1.

```
update  t
set     Version = isnull(v.Version, 0) + 1
from    inserted i
        inner join mytable t    on  i.pk = t.pk
        outer apply
        (
            select  Version = max(Version)
            from    mytable x
            where   x.DocNo = i.DocNo
        ) v
```

Answer (score 1):

Your version number is implicit in your data.  Use the PK to determine it via

`SELECT DocNo, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY DocNo ORDER BY pk) as version order by DocNo`  when you retrieve the data (or put that in a view)

Relying on IDENTITY may give you gaps

Relying on MAX(x)+1 may not always work depending on your concurrency model.

Locking the table/column will introduce concurrency issues (which may be unimportant or trivial in your case).